# Understanding how a recursive function works in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am a little bit confused on the exact execution timeline in which the following function runs. I saw this code on the MDN guide:

```
function foo (i)  {
    if (i<0) return;
    console.log('begin' + i);
    foo(i-1);
    console.log('end' + i);
}
```

Based on my knowledge of how functions work, this is what I thought, though my knowledge is inadequate:

I think when the function `foo(3)` is called, it will go to the function and check the condition `if i < 0`, then it will run the next code `console.log('begin:' +  i)`.

After that, the next line of code is executed, since JavaScript execute line by line, the next line of code which is `foo(i-1)` will be executed.

It takes the current value of `i` which is `3` minus 1, so `foo(2)` is called and the execution continues.

---

My question is: *Is my understanding correct?*. If no please explain what this code is doing, otherwise can anyone explain breiefly when will the function stop being called?

Comment: So, what *does* it do, and what are you confused about?

Comment: `foo(3)`
begin 3
begin 2
begin 1
begin 0
end 0
end 1
end 2
end 3

Comment: From your description you **do** understand how this recursive function works!

Comment: I was editing your question to improve readability, then I found actually you are not asking anything ...

Comment: what condition led to the printing out of 1, 2, and 3

Comment: First your code is evaluated up to and including line 4 (`foo(i-1)`), wich conducts the recursive call. This process builds up the stack. Then `foo(i-1)` returns `undefined` and line 5 is evaluated for each stack frame. This process unwinds the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you call `foo(3)` is as follows (in pseudocode):

```
execute foo(3)
    3 is greater than 0 thus log(begin 3)
    execute foo(2)
        2 is greater than 0 thus log(begin 2)
        execute foo(1)
            1 is greater than 0 thus log(begin 1)
            execute foo(0)
                0 is equal to 0 thus log(begin 0)
                execute foo(-1)
                    -1 is less than 0 thus return
                log(end 0)
            log(end 1)
        log(end 2)
    log(end 3)
return
```

Comment: pls        log(end 0)
            log(end 1)
        log(end 2)
    log(end 3)
return     what conditions led to the printing out of those .

Comment: @pedroyanky no conditions led to those. When the function that is called before them (eg `foo(0)`) returns, the calling function will resume execution so it will run the next line of code, which is a `log(end ...)`. Think of the `foo(number)` call inside the `foo()` function as a nother line of code that could be anything else (like for example one line like `console.log(' ')`. Hope this helps you understand how recursion works!

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:

```
foo(3)->

if (3 < 0)
  return
console.log('begin' + 3)
if (2 < 0)
  return
console.log('begin' + 2)
if (1 < 0)
  return
console.log('begin' + 1)
if (0 < 0)
  return
console.log('begin' + 0)
if (-1 < 0)
  return
console.log('end' + 0)
console.log('end' + 1)
console.log('end' + 2)
console.log('end' + 3)
```